# Deriving heterogeneity measures for each level in a multi-level moderator meta-analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis, heterogeneity

I'm running a multi-level moderator meta-analysis using the R package `metafor`. To derive $I^2$ for the metafor analysis as a whole, which doesn't come out automatically for multi-level models, I've used the formulas described [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:i2_multilevel_multivariate).

However, [I've seen meta-analysis articles](https://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/bul-a0038184.pdf) where heterogeneity measures, such as $I^2$, are reported for the individual levels in the moderator analysis.

How would these be computed? I realize that I could run subset analyses for each level, but could I somehow get the values directly from the moderator analysis? Does it even make sense to ask for heterogeneity measures for each of the levels in a moderator analysis?

Comment: Does this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187197/computing-heterogeneity-assigned-to-random-factors-in-meta-analysis/187214#187214 help?

Comment: @mdewey Thanks, I've seen that question. It seem to be about how to get $I^2$ for the overall result.

Comment: I think that if you run the example you get an $I^2$-like measure corresponding to each $\sigma^2$

Comment: Also the first link you provided explains this. See the part: "However, we can also break things down to estimate how much of the total variance can be attributed to between- and within-cluster heterogeneity separately".

Comment: @Wolfgang Wouldn't that line of code always display two numbers rather than for example 10 numbers if you have ten levels in your moderator analysis?

Comment: I think you are not fully appreciating how vectorisation works in R. WHy not just try the code and see what happens? Note that questions which are mostly code-related might be better on the mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// You do have to register first.