# How to Calculate Observed Variance in a Random-Effects Meta-Analysis

Tags: variance, meta-analysis, effect-size

I've received a revise and resubmit on a meta-analysis investigating the effects of a positive psychology intervention on depression and anxiety symptoms. I used Hedges' g as the effect size with a random effects model and the DerSimonian & Laird estimator of heterogeneity. The effect size estimates the difference between the intervention and a control group. A reviewer has asked me to report the observed variance for each meta-analysis I conduct. However, the software I'm using (OpenMEE) does not appear to report the observed variance. It calculates the individual variance for each study in the meta-analysis, but it does not provide the total variance for the meta-analysis. The results below are all the software reports. Is there a way to calculate the observed variance from the information provided in this output?

[image]

Comment: The phrase observed variance is not familiar to me. I assume R meant you to quote $\tau^2$. Why not ask the editor for clarification?

Comment: Hi mdewey, I was wondering that myself. My understanding is that τ2 is the between-study variance. However, I already reported τ2 in my manuscript, which made me think the reviewer was looking for the total variance (between study + within study variance). Do you know if there's a way to obtain the total variance for the analysis?

Comment: I think that @Wolfgang had the answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187197/computing-heterogeneity-assigned-to-random-factors-in-meta-analysis/187214#187214 here